# Check if all the values not divided by 3 in the array

Tags: javascript

I need your help.
I got a question in my Javascript course that goes like this :

Write a function that gets an array of 8 numbers, the function will print all the numbers that are divided by 3 without any remainder.

If not a single number of the array can divide by 3 without any remainder the function will print
"array not divided by 3"

So I was doing this :

```js
checkDvide=function(arr){
    arr.forEach((value,index) => {
        if(value%3==0){
            console.log(`The number ${value} is devided and his place is ${index}`)
        }
        
    });

}
```

The function working.
but how I can check the array as a whole and check if it's not divided?
thank you.

Comment: Why not diving by 3 and output the result?

Comment: Food for thought: try not to print all the numbers in the for loop, but after the loop is done. How would you go about to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could set a flag outside your loop, and if it enters your conditional, set the flag

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of if you've found anything with a boolean flag:

```js
function checkDivide(arr) {
    let found = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
        if (arr[i] % 3 == 0) {
            found = true;
            console.log(`Element at ${i} with value ${arr[i]} is divisible by 3.`);
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        console.log("None of the elements are divisible by 3.");
    }
}

console.log("first array");
checkDivide([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
console.log("second array");
checkDivide([1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myfunc(ar){
  var ans=ar.filter(function(age){
   return age%3==0;
  })
  if(ans.length==0){
   console.log("arr not divided by 3");
  }
  else {
   console.log(ans);
  }
}
var arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
myfunc(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter function, and then check the result length:

```js
checkDvide=function(arr){
    const result = arr.filter((value, index) => {
      if(!(value % 3)) {
         console.log(`The number ${value} is devided and his place is ${index}`)  
         return true
      }
     return false
    } );
    if(!result.length) {
      console.log("array not divided by 3");
    }
}

checkDvide([1,3,6,7]);
checkDvide([1,2,5,7]);
```

Comment: Happy to help :)